Is there a way to access the raw payload with a Python gRPC interceptor (server)?
is there anyway in python to get raw payload in gRPC interceptor and metadata,i need to extract signature for metadata and verify signature. in golang can achieve this by adding raw payload in context from grpc.StatsHandler
